# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' [NOT A FLOAT]

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a python program that saves a number to a file and then that reads it. (Not a float) but when I try to convert it to an int, it prints:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Any help?

**Code *snippets*:**

```
...
t= open("Bot","w+")
t.write('%d' % random.randint(1,100))
t.close()
...
t= open("Bot","w+")
num=t.read()
print(int(num))
```

Comment: If you need to read a file then you have to use `t = open("Bot","r")` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to use the r parameter. Sorry!
**complete Code snippet:**

```
...
t= open("Bot","w+")
t.write('%d' % random.randint(1,100))
t.close()
...
t= open("Bot","r") # <- Here
num=t.read()
print(int(num))
```